# How to read Wi-Fi SSID in both platforms | iOS

Tags: flutter, dart, ssid

I need to read Wi-Fi SSID from a Flutter app.

I am using [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi)

I use in a async function this code

```
String _SSID = await Wifi.ssid;
```

How can I configure the iOS platform in Xcode to make it work? Now it returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That plugin doesn't support iOS, and short of implementing the iOS side yourself that probably isn't going to change any time soon. Use the [connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) plugin instead:

```
var wifiBSSID = await Connectivity().getWifiBSSID();
var wifiIP = await Connectivity().getWifiIP();
var wifiName = await Connectivity().getWifiName();
```

The plugin documentation describes what steps to take to get it enabled for iOS.